# Modifying default MVC3 login

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, authentication

I need to slightly modify the default MVC3 login functionality.
The out of the box registration allows the user to store their **Username, Email and Password**. I would like to add **First Name and Last Name**. As well an email confirmation link sent to the registrant will be nice to have implemented.
Is it possible to accomplish this without writing my own custom membership provider ?

Answer (score 3):

I'm afraid that you will have to write some custom code.

You can use shortcuts, though, such as MVCSimpleMembership, that will allow you to use the generic createAccount method to add First and Last name (or any other custom field), and will even handle the email verification for you.

```
    var token = WebSecurity.CreateUserAndAccount("Username", "Password",
    new
    {
            FirstName = "first_name",
            LastName = "last_name",
            Email = "Email"
            }, true);
```

the token is the confirmation code you will need to send the user.

When the user returns from the confirmation link, you will use the following

```
    bool valid = WebSecurity.ConfirmAccount(token);
```